# What's the Valyrian word for “password”?

Tags: game-of-thrones, languages

I suppose there is a Valyrian word for “password”. Is it known/documented somewhere?

Comment: If you get an answer, I would recommend _not_ using that as your password.

Comment: I won't. I'd rather print a T-Shirt with “All Passwords must die.”

Comment: There's a [wiki page on learning valyrian](http://wiki.dothraki.org/Learning_High_Valyrian) (because of course there is...), and at the bottom there's a link to a dictionary... I'd be amazed if they created a word for "password" so you'll probably have to get creative, like "secret word" or something.

Comment: Speak, friend, and enter.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - Mellon

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Forgetting, for the moment, looking for a translation for 'password' and instead looking at how the sentence 'all passwords must die' works:

The phrase 'udrir morghulis' ('udir' means 'word' and so 'udrir' means 'all words') doesn't technically translate to saying 'all words must die' but actually states the 'fact' that 'all words die' - 'valar morghulis' is actually the fact that 'all men die' (interesting and irrelevant aside: this *explicitly* excludes women - the phrase 'all people die' is actually 'abrar morghulis', which is also 'all women die'). Being extremely pedantic, it's really stating the fact that 'all men are currently going towards death'

So, there are a few ways to go about this:

1. Create a valyrian word for password and put this in the statement that 'all passwords are going towards death'
2. Create a valyrian word for password and put this in the command that 'all passwords must die' (easy once 1. has been done)
3. Create a statement that says something along the lines of 'all words that allow passage die'
4. Create a command that says something along the lines of 'all words that allow passage must die'

To create a recognisable meme or somesuch, 1. would be the best option.

First of all, creating something to mean password:
the verb 'to pass' is 'rēbagon' and the noun 'word' is 'udir', so the simplest hack is just to use 'rēb' (the stem) and add 'udir' to the end.
So **The Valyrian word for 'password' is (probably) 'rēbudir'** Proncounced [reː'budir] and is a 5th declension, aquatic noun.

## Thus, 'All passwords are going towards death' translates to *'rēbudrir morghūlis'*

As 'morghūljagon' is a consonant-final verb, **commanding all passwords to die is given by 'rēbudrirzi morghūljās'**

Now, forgetting about the word for 'password', translating the phrase 'all words that allow passage':

- As before, 'all words' = 'udrir'
- 'to allow' = 'gaomagon' (consonant-final, stem = 'gaom')
- 'to pass' = 'rēbagon' (consonant-final, stem = 'rēb')

  Turning this into a relative clause (see comments) gives 'rēbagon gaomis luor udrir' as 'all words which allow to pass'.

So, the phrase **'all words that allow to pass are going to death' is 'rēbagon gaomis luor udrir morghūlis'** and giving permission for **'all words that allow to pass may die' is 'rēbagon gaomis luor udrir morghūlis kostas'**

Finally, turning this into a command gives **'all words that allow to pass must die [go to death]' as 'rēbagon gaomis luos udrirzi morghūljās'**

All of the information used above has been taken from [the Tongues of Ice and Fire Wiki](http://wiki.dothraki.org/Main_Page)

For completeness (unnecessary as it was pre-edit, but potentially interesting):

The word 'passage' (or anything that's equivalent) is the noun of the verb 'to pass', which is 'rēbagon' as before. To turn this into a noun, just add 'non' to the stem:

- 'passage' = 'rēbnon' (3rd declension, terrestrial)

Putting 'word' as the subject and 'passage' as the object creates the phrase 'udrir rēbnon gaomisi' as 'words allowing passage'. 'current words allowing passage' would be 'udrir rēbnon gaomis'

Comment: Wow. Nice. Welcome to SFF, and +1.

Comment: +1 for what looks like a very thorough post. I'm just wondering about your relative clauses—they seem odd to me. I don't know much about High Valyrian, but shouldn't “all words that allow passage” be _rēbnon gaomas luor udrir_ with a relative adjective as described [here](http://www.dothraki.com/2014/02/relative-clauses-in-high-valyrian), and “all words that allow passage are going to death” thus _rēbnon gaomas luor udrir morghūlis_? I can't make your version mean anything but ‘to die words passage to allow’… or am I missing something?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I never actually noticed this before... That explains things, thanks :) I think it would be rēbnon gaomis [singular as it allows for a passage, aortist tense] luon ['udrir' is nominative, collective, terrestrial] udrir. I'm no expert, but I think that makes sense? I'll edit the answer to include this. You're right about the other version - my lack of knowledge of relative clauses was throwing me off...

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Fixed! Either 'rēbnon gaomis luon udrir' (using a noun for passage) or 'rēbagon gaomis luon udrir' (verb rebagon used to act on gaomis to create 'all words which allow to pass') should be acceptable. Thanks for the correction :)

Comment: @Mithrandir24601 Wasn't _udrir_ aquatic (hence _luor_)? I wasn't sure if present or aorist would be better here, but I guess it's a generically true ‘allows’, so aorist is probably better, yes.

Comment: I took the liberty of making _rēbudrir morghūlis_ stand out more, since that is, I would say, the strongest and most important point of the answer.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Yes... udir is aquatic - thanks again! Also, for the command, udrirzi is vocative, so luor becomes luos. You can use the present tense - it's still a valid sentence, only the meaning changes slightly to "all words that currently allow to pass", so it depends on exactly what you want. Fair enough about editing - it does look better - I don't mind people making improvements for me!

Answer (score 4):

Password is a compound word, so based on the wiki page:

> rēbagon udir

Plural form:

> rēbagon udra

Comment: What wiki page is this from?

Comment: @Mooz I'm guessing it's [this one](http://wiki.dothraki.org/Learning_High_Valyrian)

Comment: If the info given in the other answer (and the wiki it links to) is correct, this answer is not likely to be correct. _Rēbagon_ is the infinitive meaning ‘to pass’, and since _udir_ is the same in the nominative and accusative, both in the singular and the plural, the forms given here would mean ‘to pass a word’ and ‘to pass words’, respectively.